# Opening WebView activity after google-map fragment application is getting crashed in simulator

Tags: android, google-maps, webview

Opening WebView activity after google map fragment, the application is getting crashed, if I will hide the google map fragment there is no issues WebView will work smoothly and no crash.

In the android device, it's working without any issues.

The application is crashing in the simulator in the following scenario :

CheckoutActivity(google-map fragment is present) -> PayActivity(WebView)

If I will disable google-map fragment it works

In logcat I found this:

A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0 in tid 18095 (RenderThread), pid 17947

Version Info:

google-services:4.3.3

androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0

Comment: Please provide some [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that would help the community to further check the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your AndroidManifest.xml try to add on application tag:

android:hardwareAccelerated="false"

Comment: I have added 'android:hardwareAccelerated="false"' in AndroidManifest.xml and it's started working.But now CardView is not displaying as expected, card elevation is disappeared.I don't think this is the solution.

Comment: Hi, if you have your map on a different activity you can add android:hardwareAccelerated="false" on your map activity only.

Comment: Take in mind that you can disable hardware acceleration at different levels. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel

Comment: After adding android:hardwareAccelerated="false" in activity tag the issue has been resolved.Thanks